# _tkinter.TclError: can't parse color "#158132ee"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm writing a function that converts an image to sepia tone and I'm getting this error message when I try to run it. The weirdest thing is that it did work when I ran it in activecode, the Python web interpreter in the [guide](http://www.interactivepython.org/courselib/static/thinkcspy/index.html) I'm following; cound it have to do with the image libraries I (don't) have? I'm using cImage which I downloaded from [here](https://github.com/bnmnetp/cImage), and the book mentions something called [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.1.0), but it really threw me off when I read the instructions and saw how complicated the Mac OSX install steps were compared to everything else I've done (though of course if there's no other way I'm gonna put up with it and install it anyway). Please note that I'm not sure if the guide actually USES Pillow, it just recommends it.

The function:

```
def sepiatone(i,newi):
    for col in range(i.getWidth()):
        for row in range(i.getHeight()):
            p = i.getPixel(col,row)

            newred = (p.getRed()*0.393 + p.getGreen()*0.769 + p.getBlue()*0.189)
            newgreen = (p.getRed()*0.349 + p.getGreen()*0.686 + p.getBlue()*0.168)
            newblue = (p.getRed()*0.272 + p.getGreen()*0.534 + p.getBlue()*0.131)

            newred = int(newred)
            newgreen = int(newgreen)
            newblue = int(newblue)

            newpixel = image.Pixel(newred,newgreen,newblue)

            newi.setPixel(col,row,newpixel)
```

Any help?

Comment: `#158132ee` has four bytes. It looks like `image.Pixel` is giving you an alpha component. Tcl only wants RGB, not RGBA. Consider chopping off the `ee` to get `#158132`. Or look at the documentation for image.Pixel and newi.setPixel to see whether they take RGB or RGBA.

Comment: I'd do that if I could or knew how to, but I think it's obtaining the colour from the operations – I've never actually written that specific value and assigned it to anything. I'm gonna read the documentation and see if it helps though.

Answer (score 0):

For the people that are having the same issue, all you have to do is..

```
newpixel = image.Pixel(newred/2,newgreen/2,newblue/2)
```

That worked for me.. :)